# How do I get all item of an array which doesn't exists in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can get all the items of array which do not exists another array?

I have one array with already selected values:

```
var selectedList = [1,2];
```

Another array with list of Objects like

```
var objList = [{Value:1, Name:'KL'},{Value:2, Name:'XYZ'},{Value:3, Name:'ABC'}];
```

I wanted result to be filter on value field of ObjList array and only those records come which do not exists in the selectedList.

Comment: please provide what you have tried

Comment: And show example of arrays. Much simpler for one dimensional arrays of primitives than nested arrays or arrays of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple filter to do that

```js
var selectedList = [1, 2];
var objList = [{
  Value: 1,
  Name: 'KL'
}, {
  Value: 2,
  Name: 'XYZ'
}, {
  Value: 3,
  Name: 'ABC'
}];

var data = objList.filter(x => selectedList.indexOf(x.Value) != -1)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var bigArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var smallArray = ['b', 'c', 'g'];

var newArray = bigArray.filter( function(item) {
  return smallArray.indexOf(item) < 0;
});
```

or if using `underscore.js` use `.difference()`